# How to overcome slow download of google webfonts

Tags: webfonts

I use google webfonts in my website. Unfortunately, it's Korean language and the font files are bigger than English. It's just one font-family but 3 files are downloaded (normal, bold, extra-bold). Each file is about 9MB.

When you first visit the site, it takes about 20 seconds to download the fonts and you can't see the letters. Second page is ok as the fonts are already available.

I want to workaround this problem. Is there a way to detect if the font files are already downloaded. I'd like to use a non-webfonts if the webfont is not downloaded yet. And if the webfont is downloaded, I want to set the font-family to the webfont.

I also want to implement a way to change the font-family on the fly on the first page when the download is completed.

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: I found a useful resource about this issue: http://www.atomicjetpacks.com/blog/8

Comment: I would strongly advise against using font files that huge in any case. Your mobile users and those on older networks won't appreciate 27MB of font files. Is that typical for the Korean alphabet? Do you have jQuery available? You should be able to do what you like if so.

Comment: You have the point. I am sorta hesitating using it. My designer likes it very much, though. Korean fonts are that big. There are so many letters (11,172 letters). I'll check with jQuery which I am already using.

Comment: Yeah, but you know what they say about designers. ;-)